# Flutter: Passing CollectionReferece to Stream

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I have an app that fetches data from Firestore and I want to get data and show it through StreamProvider and I need to userAdCollection inside get myAds ... they are both inside same class.

I receive this error:
Error: The getter 'userAdCollection' isn't defined for the class 'Future'.

```
class DatabaseService{

    Future addMyAds() async{
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    final CollectionReference userAdCollection = Firestore.instance.collection(user.uid);
    }

    Stream<List<AdModel>> get myAds{
        return addMyAds().userAdCollection.snapshots()
            .map(_adListFromSnapshot);
      }
}
```

and I use this class here as a value of StreamProvider:

```
return StreamProvider<List<AdModel>>.value(
  value: DatabaseService().myAds,
   Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(),)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make your getter a method that returns the stream and you should be fine! Don't forget to use the .toList() after you .map(_adListFromSnapshot)

like this:

```
Stream<List<AdModel>> myAds(){
    return addMyAds().userAdCollection.snapshots()
        .map(_adListFromSnapshot).toList();
  }
```

Comment: it did not work and gave me this error :Error: The getter 'userAdCollection' isn't defined for the class 'Future<dynamic>'.

Comment: Ottnik the code still the same buddy .. nothing changed

Comment: I changed it from a getter to a method, you can look at the last edit which happened 29 minutes ago

Comment: I received 2 errors: error: Methods must have an explicit list of parameters. (missing_method_parameters at [hpxksa] lib/services/database.dart:123) 
error: The getter 'userAdCollection' isn't defined for the type 'Future<dynamic>'. (undefined_getter at [hpxksa] lib/services/database.dart:124)